# In PhP How to know the Server IP (the main IP)

Tags: php, webserver, ip

Before I asked how to  know all the IPs available to the server. What about if I want to know the main IP?

Does a server have a main IP or all IPs are really equal?

Is it in $_SERVER array?

I am not asking about the IP of the host. I am talking about the MAIN IP. Each server has a main IP right among all those many IPs?

Answer (score 2):

The IP address of the server your script is running in is in `$_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]`, and the IP address of the client that requested the script is in `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`.

Check out [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) for more details.

Comment: Yes. I want to know the server's MAIN IP. For example, a site may be hosted at 123.123.123.005 but the server's MAIN IP may be 123.123.123.002